# Хочу спарсить информацию о кажом знаке зодиака, но class у всех одинаковый

Tags: python

как в этой ситуации поступить ?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

код:

```
URL_horoscope = "https://74.ru/horoscope/daily/"


def parser_oven(url):

    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = bs(r.text, 'html.parser')
    horoscope = soup.find_all('article', class_='IGRa5')
    return [i.text for i in horoscope]

def parser_telec(url):

    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = bs(r.text, 'html.parser')
    horoscope = soup.find_all('article', class_='IGRa5')
    return [i.text for i in horoscope]
```

ссылка на сайт - https://74.ru/horoscope/daily/

Comment: Этот функционал должен выполнять бот в виде кнопок для каждого знака зодиака, но нажимая на любую кнопку выводится горосокп для овна

Comment: выбираете все `<article class="IGRa5"/>`, поочереди парсите и складываете результат в словарик, в котором значение ключей будет названием знака зодиака, а значение - непосредственно гороскоп. Потом вытаскиваете из словарика нужный знак и все.

Comment: Я так пробовал сделать, но бот всё равно скидывает горосокоп только для овна и не парсит информацию с других знаков зодиака

Comment: по всей видимости, когда вы делали - допустили где-то ошибку.
приведите код той попытки

Comment: def parser_oven(url):

    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = bs(r.text, 'html.parser')
    horoscope = soup.find_all('article', class_='IGRa5')
    return [i.text for i in horoscope]

def parser_telec(url):

    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = bs(r.text, 'html.parser')
    horoscope = soup.find_all('article', class_='IGRa5')
    return [i.text for i in horoscope]


list_of_horoscope = {
    'oven': parser_oven(URL_horoscope),
    'telec': parser_telec(URL_horoscope)
}

Comment: будьте добры - в тексте вопроса, пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

Вариант в одну строку. Находим тэг `h3` с текстом <Название знака>, берем следующий `div` и забираем из него текст:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

URL_horoscope = "https://74.ru/horoscope/daily/"

def parser_sign(url, sign):
    return bs(requests.get(url).text, 'html.parser').find('h3', text=sign).findNext('div').text


print(parser_sign(URL_horoscope, "Дева"))
```

```
Сегодня вас может одолеть нетерпение, каковому чувству следует стойко сопротивляться. Ибо нынче оно ни к чему хорошему привести не сможет.
```